# Manipulating data through geographical (python) map visualisation

Tags: python, software-recommendations

There are many python packages that enable us to build web apps that interactively visualize data. However, I am interested in building a web application which enables the user to directly manipulate underlying data through a map visualization.

An example would be a geographical plot of shop locations, where a user can directly remove or change data related to the shops by clicking on them in the map. Thus, the user interaction in the map would then manipulate the data in the back-end (whether it is a dataframe or a database).

Unfortunately, I have extensively searched for examples of such functionality, but I was not able to find any.

I was wondering if this kind of interaction is at all possible with Python and its GIS packages?

If not, what kind of technology would I need in order to build such a web application?

Comment: maybe bokeh+holoviews+geoviews?

Comment: Are you looking for WFS-T?

Comment: GeoDjango and a Javascript front end with leaflet?

Comment: Thank you all for your comments! Bert, I have checked the docs of bokeh, holoviews/geoviews, but could not find such a functionality. Is there anything in the combination of these packages that I am overlooking? Ian, I had not heard of WFS-T before, but if I understand correctly, it is a standard protocol that enables the creation, deletion, and updating of features in an ArcGIS. Is there such equivalent for python-based packages? Spacedman, since I am not well experienced in js, I have currently made maps with geodjango + folium. Would the editing functionality work in folium?